# Are there commands that can give players permissions like "can open containers" or "can build/mine

Tags: minecraft-commands

I'm making an adventure map. One of the players is supposed to be the host and the other 3-5 Are meant to have limited permissions.

The goal is to make command blocks so there's a self destructing button that makes a person host and spawns them in the control room and the other button to remove some permissions from the rest of the players and set their world spawn to survival.

Also if you know of a way I could make a glass box appear for 2 minutes and a player tp inside it whenever they die and the box disappears letting them back in the fight that would be dope. I've been drawing a blank on that.

Comment: Thanks dude, its actually dispensers I need to lock. Will the same thing work?

Comment: This question should be closed for multiple different reasons. First, it doesn't specify which edition is being played. Second, it is far too broad, asking at least different questions ("disable block breaking/placement", "disable opening containers","create a 2-minute-duration glass box") ... and several more.

Comment: That should have been "at least 3 different questions"

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no advanced permissions system in Minecraft. But you're in luck, the two things you want specifically can be done!

The "build/mine" thing is just [Adventure mode](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Adventure) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Adventure&oldid=1356938)).

The "open chest" permission can be simulated with [locked containers(https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chest#Container) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Chest&oldid=1365036#Container)). Place the chest, hopper or other block with inventory like this:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ chest{Lock:"superSecretPassword123"}
```

Then only a player holding an item called "superSecretPassword123" can open the chest. If the players have no access to anvils, that is only those you give it to, otherwise you have to keep the name a secret or just clear any item named like this from the other players.

If you need more permissions, consider the [`/trigger` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/trigger) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/trigger&oldid=1353756)).

Comment: If anyone is wondering, this works on all blocks with inventories (Hoppers, Brewing Stands, Dispensers).